# How to pivot in two directions at once?

Tags: r, tidyr

I have example data like below, where for a unit, I have multiple treatments, and multiple measurements for each treatment in before and after periods. I want to do a before-after comparison, so I `gather`, and `spread` as shown below to achieve the desired output.

My question is: can this be done with one `pivot_` command? I have been trying to work out if a properly constructed `spec` can achieve this, but have not succeeded yet. One such attempt is below.

I think I would accept **either a way to make it work**, or a clear explanation of how `spec` or pivoting in general works that explains **why this is not possible**. From the [pivoting vignette](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html) I think I understand that:

- `.name` contains unique column names from the input table when pivoting longer
- `.value` contains new column names that you want to have in the output when pivoting longer

However, I do not know what the additional columns in `spec` mean or when they are needed. I hoped that my `spec` would understand that `"before"` values of `period` should go into a column named `before`, but apparently it doesn't work like that.

```r
library(tidyverse) # tidyr 0.8.99.9000
tbl <- tibble(
  obsv_unit = rep(1:2, each = 4),
  treatment = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 2, times = 2),
  period = rep(c("before", "after"), times = 4),
  measure1 = 1:8,
  measure2 = 11:18
)
tbl
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#>   obsv_unit treatment period measure1 measure2
#>       <int> <chr>     <chr>     <int>    <int>
#> 1         1 A         before        1       11
#> 2         1 A         after         2       12
#> 3         1 B         before        3       13
#> 4         1 B         after         4       14
#> 5         2 A         before        5       15
#> 6         2 A         after         6       16
#> 7         2 B         before        7       17
#> 8         2 B         after         8       18

tbl %>%
  gather("measure", "value", starts_with("measure")) %>%
  spread(period, value)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#>   obsv_unit treatment measure  after before
#>       <int> <chr>     <chr>    <int>  <int>
#> 1         1 A         measure1     2      1
#> 2         1 A         measure2    12     11
#> 3         1 B         measure1     4      3
#> 4         1 B         measure2    14     13
#> 5         2 A         measure1     6      5
#> 6         2 A         measure2    16     15
#> 7         2 B         measure1     8      7
#> 8         2 B         measure2    18     17

spec <- tibble(
  `.name` = c("measure1", "measure2", "measure1", "measure2"),
  `.value` = c("before", "before", "after", "after"),
  period = c("before", "before", "after", "after")
)

tbl %>% pivot_wider(spec = spec)
#> Expected a vector, not NULL
tbl %>% pivot_longer(spec = spec)
#> Failed to create output due to bad names.
#> Choose another strategy with `names_repair`
```

Comment: There's an answer to this using `reshape2::recast` https://stackoverflow.com/a/66294396/16647496. i.e. `recast(tbl, measure.var = c("measure1", "measure2"), obsv_unit + treatment + variable ~ period)`

Comment: @benson23 thanks for your comment! I looked up reshape2, and I saw that it's been superceded by tidyr. Do you know if tidyr still has a similar/equivalent functionality, or has it been left with recast2?

Comment: @Mark To my knowledge you'll need two separate pivoting operations in `tidyr` (I need to stress to my very limited knowledge) for this kind of question. Again, to my knowledge, `tidyr` and `reshape2` are two separate packages, where the former one is still in active development and the latter one is "retired" (at least shown on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/cran/reshape2)), so I'm not sure if `reshape2` is "superseded" by `tidyr` (though the author of `reshape2` recommends `tidyr`)

Comment: Besides elegance and code-golf, is there a particular reason you're trying to combine both pivots into a single step? If your real data is _huge_, there are other things you might consider (perhaps `data.table`), though in reality there's only so much "memory-efficiency" one can do when reshaping data (in either direction). (FYI, speaking of superseding, `gather` and `spread` have been superseded for several years now, in favor of the `pivot_*` functions. I made the transition a couple of years ago, and they are much more powerful with very little learning required.)

Comment: @r2evans I can't speak for OP, but for me - overwhelming amounts of laziness hahaha :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the `spec` is to handle situations with irregular patterns in column names (in wide format) and values (in long format).  It is only useful for overcoming difficulties where a regular expression + glue cannot specify the before and after. If you look at the examples in the [pivoting vignette](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html#manual-specs), it doesn't accomplish anything that couldn't be done with `rename` or `mutate` and a single pivot.

`spec` is never proposed as a method to pivot in two directions at once.

In conclusion, you need to use both `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` to accomplish this transformation.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be satisfying to you but you can do this in one operation with `reframe()` :

```
tbl %>% 
  reframe(
    .by = c(obsv_unit, treatment), 
    measure = c("measure1", 
    "measure2"), 
    after = c(measure1[period == "after"], measure2[period == 
    "after"]), 
    before = c(measure1[period == "before"], measure2[period == 
    "before"]),
  )
#> # A tibble: 8 × 5
#>   obsv_unit treatment measure  after before
#>       <int> <chr>     <chr>    <int>  <int>
#> 1         1 A         measure1     2      1
#> 2         1 A         measure2    12     11
#> 3         1 B         measure1     4      3
#> 4         1 B         measure2    14     13
#> 5         2 A         measure1     6      5
#> 6         2 A         measure2    16     15
#> 7         2 B         measure1     8      7
#> 8         2 B         measure2    18     17
```

Pivoting can be seen as a special case of aggregation.

You can also do the following for the same effect, and you might extract an helper as a spec builder :

```
tbl %>% 
  reframe(
    .by = c(obsv_unit, treatment),
    rownames_to_column(as.data.frame(t(column_to_rownames(across(everything()), "period"))), "measure")
  )
```

Comment: This was my favourite answer, but I thought (reading through the question again) because the question was asking about pivot_*(), I couldn't award the bounty to someone who didn't use pivot_longer(). Though kudos to you @moodymudskipper! :-) reframe is underutilised, and I think didn't exist when this question was created

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, it is not possible. If you look at the desired data transformation, the data basically stays in the wide format, just wide within another variable.

The `pivot_` functions can either create a long data format or a wide data format. The [pivoting vignette](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html#theory) states that "the two operations [`pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`] are symmetric". This means that you need an intermediary data transformation in the long format. To this long format, both the transformation to the original wide format as well as the new wide format are symmetric.

Transformation to the intermediary long format:

```
tbl %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(obsv_unit, treatment, period),
    names_to = "measure",
    values_to = "treatment_value"
  )

# A tibble: 16 × 5
   obsv_unit treatment period measure  treatment_value
       <int> <chr>     <chr>  <chr>              <int>
 1         1 A         before measure1               1
 2         1 A         before measure2              11
 3         1 A         after  measure1               2
 4         1 A         after  measure2              12
 5         1 B         before measure1               3
 6         1 B         before measure2              13
 7         1 B         after  measure1               4
 8         1 B         after  measure2              14
 9         2 A         before measure1               5
10         2 A         before measure2              15
11         2 A         after  measure1               6
12         2 A         after  measure2              16
13         2 B         before measure1               7
14         2 B         before measure2              17
15         2 B         after  measure1               8
16         2 B         after  measure2              18
```

Transformation to the new wide format:

```
tbl %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(obsv_unit, treatment, period),
    names_to = "measure",
    values_to = "treatment_value"
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = period,
    values_from = treatment_value
  )

# A tibble: 8 × 5
  obsv_unit treatment measure  before after
      <int> <chr>     <chr>     <int> <int>
1         1 A         measure1      1     2
2         1 A         measure2     11    12
3         1 B         measure1      3     4
4         1 B         measure2     13    14
5         2 A         measure1      5     6
6         2 A         measure2     15    16
7         2 B         measure1      7     8
8         2 B         measure2     17    18
```

The additional column in the spec [is the variable that is present in the long format, but not in the wide format of the data](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html#longer-1).

In the case of the intermediary long format, it is `measure`:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  .name    .value          measure 
  <chr>    <chr>           <chr>   
1 measure1 treatment_value measure1
2 measure2 treatment_value measure2
```

This column is the value of the `names_to` argument in `pivot_longer` and of the `names_from` argument in `pivot_wider` (if you want to reverse the `pivot_longer` transformation).